# Understanding document types in MAG and MSA Data dump

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

I am currently using Microsoft Academic's datadump for a project and  unable to identify the total number of theses & dissertations(T&D) present. Based on their website, 38% of data is categorised to OTHERS type (one among them is T&D). But their 60+GB CSV dump doesn't explicitly indicate the T&D records. Can someone help me with the statistics for T&D or how find the same?

I tried their API too and unable to find using their API too.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Academic Graph does not explicitly segment publication sub-types by thesis or dissertations, which means that neither the API or website will either.

If this is something you'd like to see added, please let them know by using the "Feedback" link in the lower-right corner on the Microsoft Academic website.